# Push element into JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to go through a JSON, if a certain condition applies then push some extra elements in that index.

I have this JS code:

```
$scope.addRoleToUser = function() {
    var userid = $scope.selectedUser;
    var tmpdata = [];
    var index = 0;
    //alert(userid);
    angular.forEach($scope.users, function(data) {

        if (data.id == $scope.selectedUser) {
            tmpdata.push(data,{"roles":[{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}]});
        }
        else {
            tmpdata.push(data); 
        }
        index++;
    });
    $scope.users = tmpdata; 
};
```

This is my initial JSON element:

```
$scope.users = [
                    {"id":"0","name":"User1","roles":[{}]},
                    {"id":"1","name":"User2","roles":[{}]},
                ]
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this after the function runs:

```
$scope.users = [
                    {"id":"0","name":"User1","roles":[{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}]},
                    {"id":"1","name":"User2","roles":[{}]},
                ]
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
[{"id":"0","name":"User1","roles":[{}]},{"roles":[{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}]},{"id":"1","name":"User2","roles":[{}]}]
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? I"m unsure of what $scope.selectedUser looks like.

Comment: ``$scope.selectedUser`` is a number that should match to one of the ``user.id``'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this inside your function

```
if (data.id == $scope.selectedUser) {
    data.roles = [{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}];
}
```

Or, if you know that roles is not empty, you can do:

```
if (data.id == $scope.selectedUser) {
    data.roles.push({"id":"00","name":"newrole"});
}
```

And after this line you can add your data to tmpdata!

That snippet now will look like this:

```
if (data.id == $scope.selectedUser) {
    data.roles = [{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}]}); //or the other one
}
tmpdata.push(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `forEach()` callback you're just working with objects and as such, you can modify them directly inside the callback:

```
angular.forEach($scope.users, function(data) {
    if (data.id == $scope.selectedUser) {
        data.roles = [{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}];
    }
});
```

Similarly you could modify almost anything of each entry by manipulating the respective `data` object.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PXyha/1/)

Comment: @LightStyle Typo. Corrected.

Comment: @LightStyle Not exactly. I generally feel it is better to explain the mistake/misunderstanding in the thought-process instead of just providing the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The Array.prototype.push method is variadic: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

When you call `tmpdata.push(a,b,c)`, you are in essence appending the array `[a,b,c]` to `tmpdata`.

You can also decompose the problem with something like:

```
$scope.addRoleToUser = function() {
  var thisUserid = $scope.selectedUser;

  function addRolesFor(user) {
    if (user.id === thisUserId){ user.roles = [{"id":"00","name":"newrole"}] };
    return user;
  }
  retrun $scope.users.map(addRoles);
}
```

Please use the `map` function that is appropriate for your environment (like `_.map`), because the `Array.prototype.map` method is not supported by all browsers.